# Is it possible to use a self expiring photo through a link to a 3rd party server as a social media profile picture?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, twitter, social-media

Suppose I have developed an app that creates encrypted images with a self expiring link that can only be opened through browser, and I want to use such service to have temporary profile picture say on facebook.

When I use Devise and OAuth in a web app, every time user signs in, e.g. with facebook credentials, it retrieves an image through a link from facebook server (of course you can optionally save the image on the app's server). I wonder if a reverse mechanism can be used to ask facebook to use a certain link for profile photo, and if nothing is available just uses a default profile photo.

Comment: You can upload images to Facebook

Comment: No, that is not possible. Facebook stores profile pictures on their own CDN and delivers them from there; you can not just make it use a URL for the profile picture. (You can upload photos from a URL – but that will just create a copy of the image on the CDN, it won’t update when the content behind that URL changes.)